# Is it possible to do animated visualizations in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to use `%matplotlib notebook` and Matplotlib `FuncAnimations` to do animated visualizations in Google Colaboratory?

When I try, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 388, in process  
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 228, in __call__  
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1560, in _stop  
    self.event_source.remove_callback(self._loop_delay)  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_callback'
```

My notebook works fine on a local Jupyter installation with Anaconda on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In the end I could hack together a somehow working solution.
It is not yet compatible with FuncAnimations but maybe you'll see how it works so I'll post it already and will modify it later on.

Put all this in one cell and run.
Once you start changing the code, make sure that the `IPython.display` functions are run from the same cell because Colaboratory creates isolated iframes for each output and both the html and javascript outputs have to end up in the same iframe.

```
import io
import numpy as np
import time
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython

def fig2b64(f):
  data = io.BytesIO()
  f.savefig(data, format='png')
  data.seek(0)
  return base64.b64encode(data.read()).decode()

f = plt.figure(num=1, clear=True)
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
line = f.gca().plot(x, y)[0]

data_str = fig2b64(f)

IPython.display.display_html(f'<img class="myimage" src="data:image/png;base64,{data_str}"></img>', raw=True)

for _ in range(10):
  time.sleep(1)
  np.random.shuffle(y)
  line.set_data(x, y)
  data_str = fig2b64(f)
  IPython.display.display_javascript(f'''
    document.querySelector('.myimage').src = 'data:image/png;base64,{data_str}';
  ''', raw=True)

# suppress final output
plt.close(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

`%matplotlib inline`

instead of

`%matplotlib notebook`